# How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, rotation, uilabel

How can you rotate text for `UIButton` and `UILabel`? 90 degrees, 180 degrees.

Comment: u just want to rotate the text or entire label/button?

Comment: [Swift version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/swift-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
[*yourlabelname* setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

rotated image
[image]

pervious image
[image]

Comment: just a minor comment; along with `M_PI` you have access to `M_PI_2` (`pi / 2`) and `M_PI_4` (`pi / 4`) so you can use those.

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
lbl.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270));
```

Comment: #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

Comment: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI_2);

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to provide an alternative response.

Instead of rotating the `UILabel`, you can rotate the text *within* the label by deriving a subclass from `UILabel` and overriding `drawRect`. If you're using Interface Builder, you can specify this subclass instead of `UILabel` in the Custom Class attribute of the Identity Inspector. This will allow you to build out your UI with XIBs, instead of programmatically creating the labels. The only caveat being that the text in Interface Builder will display horizontally. However, it will be rendered vertically in the app itself.

```
#import "RotatedLabel.h"

@implementation RotatedLabel

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -(M_PI/2));

    UIFont* systemFont17 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:systemFont17];
    CGFloat middle = (self.bounds.size.width - textSize.height) / 2;

    [self.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-self.bounds.size.height, middle) withFont:systemFont17];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

@end
```

Comment: Attempting to rotate the label inside a button will cause the label to be very short, for example, if the button is only as "wide" as the "height" of the label (when it is rotated). Applying the transform as given in the other answers to the UIButton rather than the button's label will rotate both the button and the label.

Answer (score 4):

You do like this,

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 70)];

label.numberOfLines = 2;

label.text = @"text";

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];



//rotate label in 45 degrees

label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/4 );


[self addSubview:label]; 
[label release];
```

Comment: Can i use the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation for NSString?

Comment: Maybe its make sense to combine...but maybe any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: for some strange reason when i use M_PI/4 the label disappears.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the UIView frame is changed after applying the transform, so this is what I've used:

```
    UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 28, 159)];
    l.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    l.text = @"Hello!";

    [_viewXAxisLabels addSubview:l];
    [l setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
    l.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, 28, 159);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Right To Left
lable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (3.14/2);

//Left To Right
[lable setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

OR

```
lable.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lbl.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

//Go back 

lbl.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
```