# rotating a text label

Tags: ios, calayer, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C: How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326720/objective-c-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel)

I am trying to rotate a IOS textlabel 180 degrees.
When I try rotating the label with:

```
[timeField layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

All the separate characters are rotated individually, so the resulting text is mirrored.
How can I rotate the whole label, without the mirrored order of the characters?
When I do an animation, the rotation is OK.

Comment: Around what do you want to rotate? point inside, or x-axis along?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to rotate the label with the property transform, something like:

```
timeField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (3.14/2);
```

Hope this helps