# Use Storyboard to mask UIView and give rounded corners?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, autolayout

Lots of questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182206/storyboard-and-autolayout-how-make-a-circular-image) explain how to programmatically create a mask and provide rounded corners to a UIView.

Is there a way to do it all within Storyboard? Just asking because it seems like creating rounded corners in Storyboard keeps a clearer demarcation between presentation and logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a border for UIButton in Storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477990/set-a-border-for-uibutton-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Yes, I use that a lot but question like this was already answered many times.

But anyway in Interface Builder.
You need to add User Defined Runtime Attributes like this:

```
layer.masksToBounds Boolean YES
layer.cornerRadius Number {View's Width/2}
```

[image]

and enable

```
Clips subviews
```

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: where can i add User Defined Runtime Attributes?

Comment: As I show in first image select view then on the right pane 
select third icon
User Defined Runtime Attributes
Click item below to add key path, type, value

Comment: Can you make the border radius dynamic so it's always 50% of the width or does it need to be a static integer?

Comment: As far as I know,  fixed value only.

Comment: This works on a normal UIView, or do we need to create a custom class that subclasses from UIView? We tried this on a normal UIView, and nothing happened.

Comment: Any view you name it be UIImageView, UITableCellView, UIView, UILabel or sub class from them even view that has many subviews. Can you check your **User Defined Runtime Attributes** and/or **Clips Subviews** again.

Comment: is it possible to add TopLeft, TopRIght, BottomLeft, BottomRight radii using this method?

Comment: @Zeka Dran I don't know about individual value but if it has same value you can use this method to set border radius.

Comment: @Crashalot: Did you ever get this working on a normal UIView? I also tried this on a normal UIView and nothing happened.

Comment: @AlienBishop I have just tried a minute ago and it works fine. Are you missing some value in 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'.
[Screenshot](https://s32.postimg.org/5m1r7npt1/Screen_Shot_2016_07_17_at_08_18_25.png)

Comment: how do we enable 'clip subviews'? I don't see the option in the image

Comment: @Honey I highlight the 'clip subviews' so it's standout now

Comment: Just FYI, if like me you came here thinking this would work on the LaunchScreen.storyboard, it does not. You will get:

`Error: Launch screens may not use user defined runtime attributes.`

Looks like if you need a round image on the LaunchScreen, you are out of options.

Comment: when my height and width are not the same then it's not working. could you suggest any alternative for it? Thanks!

Comment: Almost makes programmatic GUI seem easier as already making much of it programmatically in storyboards anyway.

Answer (score 26):

You can do it in a storyboard by using user-defined properties. Select the view that you want to round and open its Identity Inspector. In the **User Defined Runtime Attributes** section, add the following two entries:

- Key Path: `layer.cornerRadius`, Type: Number, Value: (whatever radius you want)
- Key Path: `layer.masksToBounds`, Type: Boolean, Value: checked

You may have to import `QuartzKit` in your view's corresponding class file (if any), but I swear that I've gotten it to work without doing that. Your results may vary.

**EDIT: Example of a dynamic radius**

```
extension UIView {

    /// The ratio (from 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive) of the view's corner radius
    /// to its width. For example, a 50% radius would be specified with
    /// `cornerRadiusRatio = 0.5`.
    @IBDesignable public var cornerRadiusRatio: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius / frame.width
        }

        set {
            // Make sure that it's between 0.0 and 1.0. If not, restrict it
            // to that range.
            let normalizedRatio = max(0.0, min(1.0, newValue))
            layer.cornerRadius = frame.width * normalizedRatio
        }
    }

}
```

I verified that this works in a playground.

Comment: Can you make the border radius dynamic so it's always 50% of the width or does it need to be a static integer?

Comment: You can, but only in code. An interesting workaround, though, is to add an IBInspectable property to your view's class that's a numeric value between 0 and 100 and indicates the percentage of the width that the radius should be. For example, a value of 50 means that the radius should be 50% of the width. Because it's a computed (not stored) property, you can even add it to an extension of UIView so that all views can have the property.

Comment: @NRitH, I would be interested to see something like that. Do you think you can post the code here?

Answer (score 25):

Use `IBInspectable` to add the properties to the Storyboard:

[image: you changed Corner Rediuse , Border Widthe and Border Color also Using StoryBord]

```
extension UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadiusV: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var borderWidthV: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var borderColorV: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why use cornerRadiusV instead of cornerRadius?

Comment: it is  set cornerRadius  using the  storyboard through, save the writing coding in Project

Answer (score 1):

> Even after making all changes in storyboard, [Woraphot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215492/1371853) doesn't work for me.

### This worked for me :

```
layer.cornerRadius = 10
layer.borderWidth = 1
layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

---

*Long answer :*

### Rounded Corners of UIView/UIButton etc

```
customUIView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

### Border Thickness

```
pcustomUIView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

### Border Color

```
customUIView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question and is just a duplicate of your [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56558934/1032372).

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect your view to your code file and then

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = yourView.frame.width / 2
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```