# UIView corner radius with UIBezierPath not working

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, uibezierpath

I am trying to set the corner radius of a UIView using UIBezierPath.
I created the following extension for this:

```
extension UIView
{    
    func roundedView(usingCorners corners: UIRectCorner, cornerRadii: CGSize)
    {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: cornerRadii)

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}


cvTutorialContainerView.roundedView(usingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight, .topLeft, .bottomLeft],
                                         cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
```

The function is being called from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
cvTutorialContainerView.roundedView(usingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight, .topLeft, .bottomLeft],
                                         cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
```

The problem is I only get a radius for the top corners, for some reasons but only on some occasions, like when using a UIPageView or an UIScrollView.

I tried `cvTutorialContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0` but it didn't work. I also tried calling the function from viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but again, no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried it. No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Why use `UIBezierPath`? You need a solution only using bezierpath?

Comment: It was the only one that partially worked for a PageView. The only one I found, at least. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have posted an answer. Do let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

Why draw a bezierPath and apply mask while you have something that does that already?

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true // You seem to be missing this part
```

If the above property is not specified, your `subviews` won't get clipped to `yourView`'s layer and that's probably why the below line didn't work for you initially

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 8 //your radius
```

P.S. You can also round specific-corners using:

```
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner] //This will round the top-left and top-right corners
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I mentioned above, I tried it already and unfortunately it doesn't work. Also, I am using clipsToBounds = true and layer.cornerRadius everywhere else in my app. The only 2 situations I am having issues with this approach are the one above (UIView and PageViewController) and for a UIView inside a UIScrollView.

Comment: Oh, but this code is supposed to work irrespective of the scenarios you mentioned. I myself have a project where I use rounded views inside scrollView and it works fine for me. Would be cool if you can provide more detail about the scenarios you're talking about (the code, I mean)

Comment: I have the following ViewControllers in this scenario: https://i.imgur.com/NkJmnwM.png The view I am trying to apply the roundedCorners to (cvTutorialContainerView) is a UIContainerView, the grey one above the Start button. The code I am using, including your suggestion, is this: https://pastebin.com/0Uy47gaj

Comment: Hmm, the code seems fine. Perhaps the place where you set the `cornerRadius` is not right but it still doesn't explain how it works for the other views. From your image, I can see that the `cvTutorialContainerView` is defined through storyboard, can you try to set the radius there like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215492/9293498

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it and it still does not work. The thing is it used to work. Initially I had an extension with predefined values. I modified the function to accept parameters and it stoped working. I changed the function back but it remained the same. And as I mentioned above, it didn't work for the views inside a UIScrollView (I changed the design on that part and I no longer need to have rounded corners there but I still found it strange). Oh, btw, I don't have Clip Subviews in Xcode, I have Clip to Bounds.

Comment: Oh, and I checked the height of the ContainerView and the attached CVs. I thought that maybe it's higher than the visible area and I simply don't see the rounded corners. Not sure if this makes any sense but it was the last thing I could think of.

Comment: Hmm, I get it. And yea, that's strange. This is probably one of those issues that require more than just snippets of code to solve