# How to rotate UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I want to know how to rotate UILabel in xcode as per attachment as watermark ("Expired").

[image: image with watermark "expired"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI /2); // set the dividend what you like
```

additional Reference see this -->  [How to angle a uilabel in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522666/how-to-angle-a-uilabel-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

The `M_PI` is changed to: `Double.pi`

```
yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Double.pi / 2)
```

Comment: Please don't repeat answers

Comment: @Chris this isn't an _exact_ repeat. but I think it would be better if it explained why use a different PI constant definition.

Comment: Isn't this actually Swift 3 code? The change from `M_PI` to `Double.pi` happened several years ago.

Comment: @HangarRash I edited it.