# How to develop a right aligned Vertical Tab in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls

My requirement is to develop a vertical tabs like safari browser tabs in iOS 6. But it should be positioned on the right.

Please see the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a UIView populated vertically by UIButtons of the tabs.

Comment: button text direction how can i achieve that

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326720/objective-c-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel