# Rotating UILabel in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a `UILabel` which I was able to rotate using the following code in iOS 7,

```
self.mylabel.text = @"Search customer";

[self.mylabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

with reference from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326720/objective-c-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel).

However, when I tried to use the similar code in iOS 8, I got a slightly different result, whereby my string look distorted and is separated into a few lines.

In iOS 7, it displays nicely in one line at a 90 degree rotation.

I wonder anyone face the same issue as me, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure the label's frame fits the text. Calling `[self.mylabel sizeToFit];` is one good way.

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried your suggestion and it's still not working.