# iOS Autolayout - How to have one sticky subview when rotating (like Native Camera App)?

Tags: ios, camera, autolayout, sticky

I am creating a custom camera and want to lock the camera controls to the bottom of the phone at all orientations

i.e. Portrait Orientation has control toolbar at bottom, Landscape Orientation has control toolbar on the left

I have been playing around with constraints and setting them for certain width/height aspects but it always rotates.
Any suggestions?

**Portrait:**
[image]

**Landscape:**
[image]

Comment: What rotates? Can you show screenshot or ideally gif image? It's difficult to understand what problem you have.

Comment: it's easy just make constraints from the bottom and with height

Comment: @Visput See attached images of default Camera App

Comment: @VarunNaharia I don't want the control to always be at the bottom of the screen regardless of orientation. I want to controls locked to the bottom of the phone (i.e. on the same side as the home button) at all times. See attached images.

Comment: Looks like you need just prevent autorotation. Select only portrait mode in project settings

Comment: your app is not rotating as in the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up locking the view to portrait orientation, then just transforming the text (I think this is how apple does it).

See this answer for transforming text: [Objective C: How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326720/objective-c-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel)